# Changing the date format in excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have an excel dataset that has dates in the following example format:
20150102 (yyyy/dd/mm),

I want to change this to the format (dd/mm/yyyy)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here are few other alternative ways, which you may find useful,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=--TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00")
```

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000\-00\-00")*1
```

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000\-00\-00")+0
```

• Formula used in cell `B5`

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000\-00\-00")/1
```

• Formula used in cell `B6`

```
=--TEXT(A2,"0000\-00\-00")
```

• Formula used in cell `B7`

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A2,"0000-00-00"))
```

• Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=TEXT(CONCAT(MID(A2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},1)),"0000\/00\/00")+0
```

• Formula used in cell `B9`

```
=TEXT(CONCAT(MID(A2,{1,5,7},{4,2,2})),"0000\/00\/00")+0
```

• Formula used in cell `B10`

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,MID(A2,{1,5,7},{4,2,2}))+0
```

• Formula used in cell `B11`

```
=TEXT(TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00")+0,"dd/mm/yyyy")+0
```

• Formula used in cell `B12`

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000-00-00")+0
```

**Note**: Since Dates are stored as numbers in Excel after applying the formulas it will show you as number if the cells are not priory formatted as Excel Dates. Hence if not formatted then please select the cell or range and press `CTRL+1` --> `Format cells` Dialogue Opens --> `Number Tab` --> `Category` --> `Custom` --> and type by removing `General` as `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Superb. Learn something new from this post.

Answer (score 3):

If `20150102` is stored as text or number then try below formula to convert it datevalue. Then use proper cell format.

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),DAY(RIGHT(A1,2)))
```

Or use `TEXT()` function to get desired format directly. Try-

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),DAY(RIGHT(A1,2))),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```