# There is a method to convert these column in data format?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format

[image: IMAGE OF EXAMPLE]

Is there a method to convert these column in data format? (gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss)

DATE : 20220601 >>>> 2022/06/01
HOUR : 3047 >>>>>    00:30:47 (hh:mm:ss)

I have serious problem with column B, i need to convert it in (hh:mm:ss). Someone can help me?

The final result should be "01/06/2022 00:30:47"

Comment: What is your `ORA` column, time? What is format for `3047`? Is it `30` hour `47` minutes?

Comment: ORA column is the hour time, in your example 3047 should be 00:30:47  (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: @NicolaTobia refer the solution, I have posted, you may try that as well, it should work for you ,

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(HourText,TEXT(B2,"000000"), 
DateText, A2,
HourFinal,TIME(LEFT(HourText,2),MID(HourText,3,2),RIGHT(HourText,2)),
DateFinal, DATE(LEFT(DateText,4),MID(DateText,5,2),RIGHT(DateText,2)),
DateFinal + HourFinal)
```

It first takes the text-hour and the text date.

Text hour is formatted as hhmmss - to have the zeros for hour if missing. Then it is easier to return the true hour.

Adding both values (date + hour (yes this is mathematical addition) returns the date.

You can then format the date as you like, e.g. as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.ss

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work, how the column should be formatted?

Comment: using the normal formatting options - do you get a result from the formula? Which Excel-Version do you have?

Comment: office 365 for enterprise, it seems excel don't read the formula

Comment: i receive this message: "the first argument of LET must be a valid name). In A2 i have the date 20220601, in B2 i have 3047, i have applied the formula on C2

Comment: What's the language of your Excel? Italian? You can use this website to "translate" the formula to your language: https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,MID(A1,{1,5,7},{4,2,2})) & " " & TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,MID(RIGHT("00"&B1,6),{1,3,5},{2,2,2}))
```

For pure date value use below function then use cell format to show your desired date/time format.

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,MID(A1,{1,5,7},{4,2,2})))+TIMEVALUE(TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,MID(RIGHT("00"&B1,6),{1,3,5},{2,2,2})))
```

[image]

Comment: formula are not working for my Excel

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ***easy alternative solution***, using the `TEXT()` Function with a ***Custom Formatting*** for **Dates** `0000\/00\/00` while for **Times** `00\:00\:00`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00")+TEXT(B2,"00\:00\:00")
```

---

So, the **first part** of the `TEXT()` function returns & converts the **Numbers** into **Dates**, while the **second part** returns & converts the **Numbers** into **Times**, and as we know that **Dates & Times** are stored as **Numbers** in **Excel**, so the **Integer** part which represents the Dates and the **Decimal** which represents **Times**, when added to together returns a **Number with Decimals** using the `TEXT()` Function.

Hence if the cells are not formatted before then please select the cell or range and press `CTRL+1` --> `Format cells Dialogue Opens` --> `Number Tab` --> `Category` --> `Custom` --> and type by `removing General` as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or as per your region it will be `gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss`

---

**Note:** For more **inspiration** on converting Dates when shown like those numbers, you can refer this link, I have shared a whole lot of alternatives.

**[CHANGE THE DATE FORMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72716464/8162520)**