# Excel formula to insert special characters into number string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem
I have a process that strips out all the characters and spaces from a cell containing text until it leaves me with just the shift times. The cell containing the text is free type for useability and that means the best option i've found is to strip the cell contents down to what i need then rebuild it to a number formation with a "-" in the middle for text to columns to split it and then work out the shift hours.

This is where the issue is. Once i've just got the numbers I need to insert a : between the second and third number and between the sixth and fifth number. I have the below formula that a member of this site put forward and it works great but i need to adapt it to insert the - character in the middle of the 8 numbers.

=RIGHT(LEFT(E2880,FIND("-",E2880,1)-3),2)&":"&LEFT(RIGHT(E2880,LEN(E2880)-FIND("-",E2880,1)+3),5)&":"&LEFT(RIGHT(E2880,LEN(E2880)-FIND("-",E2880,1)-2),2)

so Ideally the formula would turn this
22000900
into this
22:00-09:00

Can anybody help? the formula is confusing me.

cheers

Comment: What is your excel version? Is it Excel-365?

Comment: Yes its office 365

Comment: Bit similar query for @MJobbson reference: **[Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73268730/8162520)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Microsoft-365` could try-

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",1,MAP(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)/4,,,4),4),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(":",1,MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)/2,,,2),2)))))
```

More generic formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",1,MAP(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)/(LEN(A1)/2),,,LEN(A1)/2),LEN(A1)/2),
LAMBDA(x,
TEXTJOIN(":",1,MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)/(LEN(x)/2),,,LEN(x)/2),LEN(x)/2))
)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00\:00-00\:00")
```

Funny enough, you could also split this immediately and have Excel recognize your value as a number representation of these time-values (and use a numberformat on these cells if you so desire). Either through splitting the previous mentioned method:

```
=--TEXTSPLIT(TEXT(A1,"00\:00-00\:00"),"-")
```

Or, something different alltogether:

```
=--REPLACE(MID(A1,{1,5},4),3,,":")
```

[image]

---

**Note:** It won't matter for `TEXT()` if input is a string or number.

Comment: ha ha ha. I have thanked complicated and forgot to apply simple formatting. Cool solution. OP can directly apply this `00\:00-00\:00` formatting to cell format instead of using formula.

Comment: applying to custom cell formatting is facade, it won't make any difference, but using a formula with `TEXT( )` would have the change actually, because if you see the formula bar it would still show as `22000900` where as using a formula it would be always `00\:00-00\:00` so there is a difference between custom cell formatting and custom formatting using a formula.

Answer (score 2):

Little bit simpler solution.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(":",1,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)/2,,,2),2)),":","-",2)
```