# Excel - add slashes after every two numbers, keep leading zero and keep these in results of referring formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In A1 - entering 070123, for date (don't want to enter slashes manually)

But the outcome desired is for Excel to "convert" that entry to 07/01/23 automatically.

Tried custom cell formatting to `##"/"##"/"##` but it drops leading zero and results in 7/01/23 instead of 07/01/23

Another problem is that result in cells referring to this formatted cell A1 still missing slashes, like 70123 instead of either 7/01/23 or 07/01/23

Talking about formulas like: `="Sent on " & A1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>TEXT( )</kbd> Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/00")+0
```

---

For your second question:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
="Sent on "&TEXT(TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/00")+0,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

---

For reference:

[image]

---

As I have said in comments above that custom formatting is **facade**, you can refer the screenshots, use the formula instead.

---

Another approach you can use:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,MID(A1,{1,3,5},{2,2,2}))+0
```

---

> **Note:** *Since **Dates** are stored as **numbers** in Excel after applying the formulas it will show you as **number** if the cells are
> not priory formatted as Excel Dates. Hence if not formatted then
> please select the cell or range and press*
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> --> <kbd>Format cells</kbd> *Dialogue
> Opens -->* <kbd>Number Tab</kbd> --> <kbd>Category</kbd> -->
> <kbd>Custom</kbd> --> *and type by removing* <kbd>General</kbd> *as*
> <kbd>mm/dd/yyyy</kbd> *or you can select the Date formatting and
> choose the preferred type.*

---

Reference for multiple approaches: **[Changing the date format in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72716464/8162520)**

Comment: using =TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/00")+0 for 070123 in A1 results in 4/51/08

Comment: @Cap'nCrunch you refer my screenshot it does works on my end, may I know what is your regional settings? Your cell if formatted as `Text` change the cell format as `Date` after that press function key `F2` and hit enter